# Set HttpOnly for all cookies in spark-java

Tags: java, embedded-jetty, spark-java

I developed a web UI to configure a device. To secure this UI which achieves OWASP top 10 and fix bug that reported by Acunetix application, some improvement must be done on it. One of them is setting HTTP-ONLY for cookies.
How can change/set cookie default attribute in java-spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
//set HttpOnly properties for all cookies
for (String key : cookies.keySet()) {
    if (key != null) {
        response.removeCookie(key);
        response.cookie("/", key, cookies.get(key), 200, false, true);
    }
}
```

Note that it is not possible to change settings of jetty through spark. Adding such feature to spark can considerably facilitate the process of changing cookie-related settings.